# Como puedo obtener la frecuencia de un # en una fila de un dataframe en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, frecuencia

Necesito obtener la frecuencia de una fila. Para ello he probado varios métodos pero lamentablemente no cumplen con lo que necesito.
El valor devuelto de debe mostrar como de la siguiente forma.

```
  a b 
0 1 17
1 0 11
```

Es decir el 1 se repite 17 y 0 11

He probado con los métodos `value_counts()` y `count()`
El primer método me muestra los valores que se repiten como índice por lo que no los puedo seleccionar para luego establecer ciertas condiciones. Y el segundo método sólo lo puedo usar en las filas con listas, no me deja usar `dataframe`. Entonces en resumen obtener la frecuencia de un # número en una fila donde pueda seleccionar el # que se repite y la frecuencia. Por favor alguien me podría ayudar con este problema.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ¿Podrías agregar algunas filas de  tu `dataframe` y el código que tienes con lo que has intentado?